# Why do safety requirements like to discourage use of AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, requirements

Seems that requirements on safety do not seem to like systems that use AI for safety-related requirements (particularly where large potential risks of destruction/death are involved). Can anyone suggest **why**? I always thought that, provided you program your logic properly, the more intelligence you put in an algorithm, the more likely this algorithm is capable of preventing a dangerous situation. Are things different in practice?

Comment: "Three laws safe" works in theory, not in practice ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most AI algorithms are *fuzzy* -- typically learning as they go along. For items that are of critical safety importance what you want is deterministic.  These algorithms are easier to prove correct, which is essential for many safety critical applications.

Comment: At a minimum you need, deterministic and comprehensible behavior at the interlock level. Any reasons---other than culture bias---not to use fuzzy stuff to provide a predictive alert layer?

Comment: It occur to me that the answer to my own question is probably "Resources". As in, they are better spent on more deterministic code, or more thorough validation. ::sigh::

Answer (score 6):

I would think that the reason is twofold.

First it is possible that the AI will make unpredictable decisions.  Granted, they can be beneficial, but when talking about safety-concerns, you can't take risks like that, especially if people's lives are on the line.

The second is that the "reasoning" behind the decisions can't always be traced (sometimes there is a random element used for generating results with an AI) and when something goes wrong, not having the ability to determine "why" (in a very precise manner) becomes a liability.

In the end, it comes down to accountability and reliability.

Comment: Your second point, that reasoning is often non-auditable, is a very real concern.

Answer (score 4):

The more complex a system is, the harder it is to test. 
And the more crucial a system is, the more important it becomes to have 100% comprehensive tests.

Therefore for crucial systems people prefer to have sub-optimal features, that can be tested, and rely on human interaction for complex decision making.

Answer (score 4):

From a safety standpoint, one often is concerned with guaranteed predictability/determinism of behavior and rapid response time.  While it's possible to do either or both with AI-style programming techniques, as a system's control logic becomes more complex it's harder to provide convincing arguments about how the system will behave (convincing enough to satisfy an auditor).

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that AI systems are generally considered more complex. Complexity is usually a bad thing, especially when it relates to "magic" which is how some people perceive AI systems.

That's not to say that the alternative is necessarily simpler (or better).

When we've done control systems coding, we've had to show trace tables for every single code path, and permutation of inputs. This was required to insure that we didn't put equipment into a dangerous state (for employees or infrastructure), and to "prove" that the programs did what they were supposed to do.

That'd be awfully tricky to do if the program were fuzzy and non-deterministic, as @tvanfosson indicated. I think you should accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

The key statement is "provided you program your logic properly". Well, **how** do you "provide" that? Experience shows that most programs are chock full of bugs.

The only way to guarantee that there are no bugs would be formal verification, but that is practically infeasible for all but the most primitively simple systems, and (worse) is usually done on specifications rather than code, so you still don't know of the code correctly implements your spec after you've proven the spec to be flawless.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because AI is very hard to understand and that becomes impossible to maintain.

Even if a AI program is considered fuzzy, or that it "learns" by the moment it is released, it is very well tested to all know cases(and it already learned from it) before its even finished. Most of the cases this "learning" will change some "thresholds" or weights in the program and after that, it is very hard to really understand and maintain that code, even for the creators.

This have been changing in the last 30 years by creating languages easier to understand for mathematicians, making it easier for them to test, and deliver new pseudo-code around the problem(like mat lab AI toolbox)

Answer (score 1):

As there is no accepted definition of AI, the question shall be more specific.

My answer is on adaptive algorithms merely employing parameter estimation - a kind of learning - to improve the safety of the output information. Even this is not welcome in functional safety although it may seem that the behaviour of a proposed algorithm is not only deterministic (all computer programs are) but also easy to determine.

Be prepared for the assessor asking you to demonstrate test reports covering all combinations of input data and failure modes. Your algorithm being adaptive means it depends not only on current input values but on many or all of the earlier values. You know that a full test coverage is impossible within the age of the universe.

One way to score is showing that previously accepted simpler algorithms (state of the art) are not safe. This shall be easy if you know your problem space (if not, keep away from AI).

Another possibility may exist for your problem: a compelling monitoring function indicating whether the parameter is estimated accurately.

Comment: On too simple algorithms: "The point of approximation is to tractably preserve as much application realism as possible—not to achieve tractability under simplistic assumptions." from Ronald Mahler (Lockheed Martin), [Random Sets: Unification and Computation for Information Fusion—A Retrospective Assessment](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/0b386511a21614791711280c.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are enough ways that ordinary algorithms, when shoddily designed and tested, can wind up killing people. If you haven't read about it, you should look up the case of [Therac 25](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3604/lib/Therac_25/Therac_1.html). This was a system where the behaviour was supposed to be completely deterministic, and things still went horribly, horribly wrong. Imagine if it were trying to reason "intelligently", too.

Comment: Harm would have been prevented.

Answer (score 0):

"Ordinary algorithms" for a complex problem space tend to be arkward. On the other hand, some "intelligent" algorithms have a simple structure. This is especially true for applications of Bayesian inference. You just have to know the likelihood function(s) for your data (plural applies if the data separates into statistically independent subsets).

Likelihood functions can be tested. If the test cannot cover the tails far enough to reach the required confidence level, just add more data, for example from another sensor. The structure of your algorithm will not change.

A drawback is/was the CPU performance required for Bayesian inference.

Besides, mentioning Therac 25 is not helpful, since *no algorithm at all* was involved, just multitasking spaghetti code. Citing the authors, "[the] accidents were fairly unique in having software coding errors involved -- most computer-related accidents have not involved coding errors but rather errors in the software requirements such as omissions and mishandled environmental conditions and system states."